# AJAX call sends data via POST, but PHP doesn't receive

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

So, I have this really weird problem. I have constructed a web application with a login form on my home pc, but when I try to migrate it to a server with domain, php went all crazy and everything doesn't work anymore now.

So I have a login form, which sends the data via an AJAX POST call to a php file, which compares the given data to the interface. But it seems that in one way or another, the data isn't getting received by the php. Let me show you what my setup is:

the Javascript:

```
    console.log(username);
    $.ajax({
        url: "server/login_server.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "JSON",
        data: {username: username, password: password},
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);

            if(data.responseText == "SUCCESS") {
                location.assign("pages/overview.html");
            }else if(data.responseText == "ERROR_CONNECT") {
                showError("kan niet verbinden met server");
            }else if(data.responseText == "ERROR_CODE") {
                showError("Er is iets misgelopen...");
            }else if(data.responseText == "ERROR_FALSE") {
                showError("Inloggegevens ongeldig");
            }else if(data.responseText == "ERROR_MULTIPLE") {
                showError("Er zijn meerdere resultaten gevonden");
            }else if(data.responseText == "ERROR_FORBIDDEN") {
                showError("Dit account heeft geen admin-privileges");
            }

            $("#login_password").val("");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Some lines are written in dutch, but don't worry, it doesn't say anything important. The console (on line 1) clearly writes the username, so I know that the username value isn't empty.

The PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$config = include('config.php');

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$conn = new mysqli($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'],      $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);

$result = "SUCCESS";

if($conn->connect_error) {
    $result = $conn->connect_error;
    die($result);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName='".$username."'";
$status = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(!$status) {
    $result = "ERROR_CODE";
    die($result);
}

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($status);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($status);

if($num_rows == 0) {
    $result = "ERROR_FALSE";
    die($username);
}else if($num_rows > 1) {
    $result = "ERROR_MULTIPLE";
    die($result);
}else{
    if($row['isAdmin'] == "false") {
        $result = "ERROR_FORBIDDEN";
        die($result);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['logedIn'] = "true";
        $result = "SUCCESS";
        die($result);
    }
}

echo $username;
?>
```

It is a simplistic representation of what I am trying to do, but this is where it goes wrong. It gets the username from the post call, and gives it back as data.responsetext to the javascript file.

The javascript file in its turn, prints out an empty string as the result of the php file.

Firebug log:

[image: Firebug log]

Adding the full error log gives me the following:

```
"<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: conn in    <b>/home/netwerklevensein/public_html/dagboek/server/login_server.php</b> on   line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource,    string given in    <b>/home/netwerklevensein/public_html/dagboek/server/login_server.php</b> on    line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: conn in    <b>/home/netwerklevensein/public_html/dagboek/server/login_server.php</b> on   line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource,    string given in <b>/home/netwerklevensein/public_html/dagboek/server/login_server.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
"
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Look at what you're echoing `echo $username;` and look at what your 1st line is `$username2 = $_POST['username'];` or is that just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, typo, I will correct it, still doesn't work though.

Comment: What does `console.log(data.responseText);` output?

Comment: did you check you apache logs

Comment: ah, had a feeling it was. Well, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and check your console. We don't know what your HTML looks like.

Comment: So, as said, the php file was a simplified one. I actually used the string $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); and that didn't return anything, but when i removed the mysql_real_escape_string part, everything started working again... any idea why?

Comment: give the entire php response please

Comment: console.log(data); and check the object

Comment: @zenodhaene if you're connecting with `mysqli_` or PDO (another unknown), then that's the problem. You can't mix those different APIs. Edit: there you, can't mix those.

Comment: **people down (so far) there are NOT paying attention to comments/edits.**

Comment: @ Fred -ii- the database connection isn't the problem.

Comment: @MohammedSafeer: "Array\n(\n    [username] =...  [password] => test\n)\n"

Comment: You aren't checking the user's password, you should also hash passwords. Also outputting `ERROR_CODE` isn't going to be useful; you should use the error function.

Comment: @Fred-ii- o now I get it

Comment: @zenodhaene I posted my answer below.

Comment: Find the cause of the problem. Is php returning valid json? is the ajax firing the error callback? have you looked at your network tab?

Comment: @KevinB if it isn't valid JSON, then error reporting should be throwing them back something about it.

Comment: JSON.parse("SUCCESS") of course throws an error, so once whatever problem is causing php to return an empty string is resolved, it's going to end up in the error callback.

Comment: @KevinB I am not parsing a string anywhere?

Comment: By using `dataType: 'json'`, you are telling jQuery to do that for you.

Comment: @KevinB True and is most likely being broken by their escape function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing MySQL APIs here with (connecting with mysqli_ then using mysql_ escape functions).

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

that should read as

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
```

Those different APIs do NOT intermix.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Check for errors against your query also:

```
$status = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Your code gives me the following responsetext;  "<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  U...on line <b>9</b><br />\n" But when I don't use the escape-string part, the code is executing just fine?

Comment: @zenodhaene that message is unclear, and seems to be an Undefined index notice. You should be posting your HTML form as I suggested in comments. Plus, make sure your JSON is valid. Look at some of the other answers given.

Comment: @zenodhaene I believe that the escaping is throwing out valid characters. It's most likely the JSON declaration for it. If JSON isn't being passed in there, then you shouldn't use JSON, far as I can tell. See the other answers and a few new ones about it. such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/34439563/

Comment: @zenodhaene that undefined variable conn notice. This tells me your connection file isn't correct and/or there is an error of syntax. Replace what you have now with a standard connection method as outlined in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php `$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");` I believe that is the root of the problem here, in regards to that first notice. The `mysql_` functions will need to be changed to what I included in my answer.

Comment: the connection is working just fine, since I can pull data out of the database. The only problem I have is the variable not coming through in php when I try to mysql_real_escape_string it. When I leave that out, it processes just fine. I guess I will do that in the javascript then.

Comment: @zenodhaene Most bizarre seeing `Undefined variable: conn in...` though. Well, I'm sure you'll get success, *cheers* and Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 0):

You can print

```
echo json_encode(array('username' => $username2));
```

cause, you set output format is JSON.
Another thing, you can use **success** handler on ajax request, and use only response message (not all XMLHttpRequest response)

Answer (score 0):

I am not a php expert but looks like you are missing some thing on Ajax calls.

Here are my suggestions:
To post Json you need to stringify  using  JSON.stringify(data)
Also dont forget to set processdata option to false.

Please place the blow lines inside your ajax call after  data: {username: username, password: password},

data: JSON.stringify(data),
processData: false,

Answer (score 0):

try this in php,

```
echo json_encode(
     array('responseText' => $result)
);
```

You are trying to access `responseText` property from data object. And echo only `$username` string

Answer (score 0):

I see in your AJAX code that you said you are receiving JSON data, but in the php file you just issued an echo or die and that ain't JSON data but plain text. So try to put `datatype: "text"` on the AJAX code.